# How to recognize removable discontinuities.

Tags: complex-analysis

In regards to complex analysis, what's a good sign that I may have a removable discontinuity? I understand that in some cases it's as simple as

$$\frac{z^3 + 1}{z+1}$$

where $z+1$ is a factor on the numerator.

But in a recent case, I came across

$$\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2} - \frac{3}{z}.$$

At first I thought "pole, order 2" but the discontinuity at $z=0$ turned out to be removable. I get it, I think. As $z \rightarrow 0$, $\sin(3z)/z \rightarrow 3$. So this function acts like $3/z - 3/z = 0$ at $z=0$. We can simply redefine the function to have this value at $z= 0$, and this satisfies the condition of a removable discontinuity.

This example wasn't immediate to me. I'd like to train my eye to better classify discontinuities, and I was hoping someone could offer a list of scenarios or perhaps a condition where discontinuities are removable.

Comment: In this case, you can write $\sin(3z) = 3z-\frac{(3z)^3}{3!}+\frac{(3z)^5}{5!} -...$. And then what happens, is that $\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2} -\frac{3}{z}$ "looks like" $$\bigg(\frac{3}{z} - \frac{3^3z}{3!} +\frac{3^5z^3}{5!} -...\bigg) - \frac{3}{z} = - \frac{3^3z}{3!} +\frac{3^5z^3}{5!} -...$$, and you can clearly see with your eyes that there is an entire extension of this function, since we have a power series with nonnegative powers which converges everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @Shalop. That is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lim_{z\to p}f(z)$ exists then $p$ is a removable singularity.

Comment: A finite limit. Got it. Poles would be unbounded. Essential singularities assume all complex numbers with possible exception of one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should use asymptotic expansions to understand the behaviour, not only for meromorphic functions but in general. To make clear what *Shalop* said, you can explicitly do the following:

As $z \to 0$:

$\dfrac{\sin(3z)}{z^2} - \dfrac{3}{z}$

$\in \dfrac{3z-\frac{1}{6}(3z)^3 + O(z^5)}{z^2} - \dfrac{3}{z}$

$= \dfrac{-\frac{1}{6}(3z)^3 + O(z^5)}{z^2}$

$= -\frac{9}{2}z + O(z^3)$  [since $z \ne 0$]

$\subseteq 0 + o(1)$.

This shows that the singularity at $0$ is removable, since the function tends to $0$ at $0$. Similarly you might find it fun to explore the asymptotic behaviour of the following:

- $\dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{n-1}$ as $n \to \infty$.
- $\dfrac{1}{\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor }$ as $x \to 0$.
- $x+|x|^{2.5} \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor$ as $x \to 0$. (This one is differentiable at $0$ despite being not invertible in any open interval around $0$!)